# Wordpress Editor is converting my php code oddly

Tags: php, wordpress

The Wordpress editor in Text mode is converting about half of the greater than and less than signs to encoded format.  It's also taken the following code:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

and changed it to this:

```
<a class="mceWpPHP" title="php" href="&lt;img src=">"&gt;<?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

I am using a plugin called "PHP Execution" that enables the use of PHP in pages.  I don't know if it's related to the problem.

With Wordpress doing this, I can't edit php in my pages at all.

Comment: Being able to edit `php` live on the server said `php` is running on using code at best tangential to said `php` and at worst reliant on it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: TinyMCE (the wordpress editor) strips out php unless you use a plugin that allows it, the &gt; and &lt; are the html entity representations of > and <.  Anytime you're using a WYSIWYG editor it's probably going to strip out any scripting, they're not really designed for it.  You need to edit the template that renders the post content itself to use php.  You can find what template you need to edit here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy